# Same goes for me as well

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this sentence redundant?

> The same goes for me as well.

Since we are already using "the same," I feel like "as well" is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English is full of redundant phrases used to produce some effect. Without knowing the context it's impossible to say, but one common reason can be to produce longer sentences to avoid appearing terse or cold. This is also pretty common in other languages (eg. Mandarin's 如果...的话, both sides of which individually imply "if", but either (or sometimes even both) could be omitted).

Otherwise, all of these are fine:

> The same [goes] for me as well.

> The same [goes] for me.

> For me as well.

> Me too.

Comment: You might want to add that the phrase in the question and in all of your examples are not just *fine*, but are in fact idiomatic.  Expressions in common use with subtle differences in tone but the same meaning.